# Compatibility of different SVN GUIs

Tags: macos, svn, cross-platform, tortoisesvn

Is there any way I can work on a Tortoise SVN repository from a Mac? Could I download a Mac equivalent and work on it without issues? It would be for Unreal Engine 4 if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever SVN client you prefer; Tortoise SVN is strictly an interface on top of subversion, not subversion in it's entirety.

SVN Clients like [Versions](https://versionsapp.com/) or [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) are compatible SVN clients for MacOS. Conversely, you can install subversion and use strictly the command line tools if you prefer. Versions is pretty highly regarded from my experience with users on MacOS with subversion clients.